# vba binary file cause overflow

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, ms-word

I'm trying to write this data to a binary file using a macro in word.
If I run this I get this error **"Execution error Overflow (Error 6)"** on the line   *Put #handle, , CByte("&H" & output(i))*

How can I fix this?
Thanks.

```
Sub HexStringToBinaryFile()


    lol50

    Dim output() As String
    output = Split(lol, "|")

    Dim handle As Long
    handle = FreeFile
    Open "C:\test.bin2" For Binary As #handle

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(output) To UBound(output)

        Put #handle, , CByte("&H" & output(i))

    Next i

    Close #handle

End Sub
  Sub lol50()
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|01"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|02"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|03"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are not putting a delimiter on the end of your `lol` assignment lines. So when they are split, the last 2 digits of the previous line are concatenated with the first 2 line of the next.

The error occurs here:

```
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|01"
lol = lol & "00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|40|00|00|00|00|00|00|00"
```

When this is parsed, there is no separator between `01` and `00` (on the next line) so the value of `0100` produces the overflow.

End each of your `lol` assignment lines with a `|` and the error should go away.

Answer (score 1):

Jason has the right answer, but I'm not sure building up a string and splitting it to get an array is the best way. You might consider just filling an array directly.

```
Private lol(1 To 4656) As String

Sub HexStringToBinaryFile()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim handle As Long

    lol50

    handle = FreeFile
    Open "C:\test.bin2" For Binary As #handle
        For i = LBound(lol) To UBound(lol)
            Put #handle, , CByte("&H" & lol(i))
        Next i
    Close #handle

End Sub
Sub lol50()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 4656
        lol(i) = "00"
    Next i

    For i = 9 To 4656 Step 16
        lol(i) = "40"
    Next i

    lol(4000) = "01"
    lol(4416) = "02"
    lol(4656) = "03"

End Sub
```